# Rails 5 issue with doing a search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, controller, ruby-on-rails-5

I've spent almost a day on this problem and cannot seem to figure it out. I have a form on my index.html.erb page that is a search for and looks something like this:

```
<%= form_with(url: "/search", method: "get") do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :Start_date %>
    <%= f.date_select :date_out %>

    <%= f.label :End_Date %>
    <%= f.date_select :endDate %>
    
    <br>
    <p>Enter Report Type:</p>
    <%= select_tag :reportType,
      options_for_select([['sale', 'sale'], ['received', 'received'], ['po', 'po'], ['invoice', 'invoice']]) %>
    <br>

    <%= submit_tag("Show Report") %>

  <% end %>
```

In my controller I have a search action that looks like this:

```
class ItemInstancesController < ApplicationController
  def search
    # Converting the string params to a Date
    startDate = Date.new(params["date_out(1i)"].to_i, params["date_out(2i)"].to_i, params["date_out(3i)"].to_i)
    endDate = Date.new(params["endDate(1i)"].to_i, params["endDate(2i)"].to_i, params["endDate(3i)"].to_i)

    # Getting the params from what the user submitted 
    reportType = params[:reportType]

    if reportType == 'po'
      
      # I have to do a search of the item_instances model to pull based on the date range of the date_out column 
      @item_instances = ItemInstance.search_for_records_by_date(startDate, endDate).order("po_number ASC")
      format.html { render :search }
    end 

  end 
end
```

The problem is that I'm not going to the search page when I hit my form. I can see my params coming in just fine. This is what I see in the terminal when I hit the show report button:

```
Started GET "/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&%5Bdate_out(1i)%5D=2020&%5Bdate_out(2i)%5D=8&%5Bdate_out(3i)%5D=11&%5BendDate(1i)%5D=2020&%5BendDate(2i)%5D=8&%5BendDate(3i)%5D=11&reportType=po&commit=Show%20Report" for 10.9.0.201 at 2020-08-11 15:40:00 -0400
Cannot render console from 10.9.0.201! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by ItemInstancesController#search as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "date_out(1i)"=>"2020", "date_out(2i)"=>"8", "date_out(3i)"=>"11", "endDate(1i)"=>"2020", "endDate(2i)"=>"8", "endDate(3i)"=>"11", "reportType"=>"po", "commit"=>"Show Report"}
2020-08-11
2020-08-11
po
  ItemInstance Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `item_instances`.* FROM `item_instances` WHERE `item_instances`.`date_out` BETWEEN '2020-08-11' AND '2020-08-11' ORDER BY po_number ASC
  ↳ app/controllers/item_instances_controller.rb:28
#<ItemInstance:0x00007f06bc1209e8>
#<ItemInstance:0x00007f06bc1208a8>
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)


  
ArgumentError (too few arguments):
  
app/controllers/item_instances_controller.rb:29:in `format'
app/controllers/item_instances_controller.rb:29:in `search'
```

I also do not know why my form is being processed as JS and not HTML. When I submit the form nothing happens on the web page - meaning it stays on the index.html.erb. Finally, my routes look like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :item_instances
  get '/search', to: 'item_instances#search'

  resources :items

  # Route to the home page 
  root 'home#index'
  
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

And the model is this:

```
  create_table "item_instances", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "inv_number"
    t.string "serial"
    t.integer "po_number"
    t.date "po_date"
    t.date "invoice"
    t.date "date_out"
    t.decimal "cost", precision: 8, scale: 2
    t.string "acro"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "item_id"
    t.index ["item_id"], name: "fk_rails_6ea33fd9d0"
  end
```

Thank you for any help that may be provided.

Here is the index.html.erb file:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Item Instances</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Inv number</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Serial</th>
      <th>PO number</th>
      <th>PO date</th>
      <th>Invoice</th>
      <th>Date Out</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
      <th>Acro</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @item_instances.each do |item_instance| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= item_instance.inv_number %></td>
        <td><%= link_to item_instance.item.description, edit_item_instance_path(item_instance)%></td>
        <td><%= item_instance.serial %></td>
        <td><%= item_instance.po_number %></td>
        <td><%= item_instance.po_date %></td>
        <td><%= item_instance.invoice %></td>
        <td><%= item_instance.date_out %></td>
        <td><%= item_instance.cost %></td>
        <td><%= item_instance.acro %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', item_instance %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_item_instance_path(item_instance) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', item_instance, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>


<%= form_with(url: "/search", method: "get") do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :Start_date %>
    <%= f.date_select :date_out %>

    <%= f.label :End_Date %>
    <%= f.date_select :endDate %>
    
    <br>
    <p>Enter Report Type:</p>
    <%= select_tag :reportType,
      options_for_select([['sale', 'sale'], ['received', 'received'], ['po', 'po'], ['invoice', 'invoice']]) %>
    <br>

    <%= submit_tag("Show Report") %>

  <% end %>

<%= link_to 'New Item Instance', new_item_instance_path %>
```

Here is the search.html.erb page: (I just want the page to display heading at this point)

```
<h1>Report Page</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default for `form_with` is to send your form remotely. That is why you are seeing `Processing by ItemInstancesController#search as JS`. If you add `local: true` to your form, you should hit `format.html` in your controller. You can read more about form_with [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with).

Answer (score 0):

Your `format` has to be inside a `respond_to` block

```
respond_to do |format| 
  format.html { render :search }
end
```

or you might get away with just

```
render :search
```

Comment: Is the header `Report Page` not shown after you are redirected?

Comment: No it's not, I stay on the index.html.erb page. What's frustrating is the terminal is showing that it should be rendered and it's not.